# How to fix source is empty error in XML source while using Foreach loop container in SSIS 2012?

Tags: variables, ssis, mapping, foreach-loop-container

I have an issue with a very simple task in SSIS 2012.

I have a for-each container that runs in FOR-EACH-FILE Enumerator mode. I want to read a target folder with XML files. The path to the folder is correctly configured. The files field is set to *.xml

The variable mapping is defined with the follwing Variable: User::FileVar , Index 0.

Now I add a simple data flow task inside the container. The dataflow task only has a XML-Data Source task, that's it. For the  XML Data source task, the XSD location is set. When I click choose columns, I can see the columns from the XSD schema.

BUT: When I save the XML task , I always get the error message: `The Property XMLDataVariable is empty`. I tried both  data Access modes, XML file from variable and XML data from variable. The error message remains, I cannot run the package.

I don't use any expressions, neither at the foreach loop container nor at the data flow task.

I dont know what's wrong here, I did the steps exactly as shown in some tutorials for older versions of SSIS.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @Siva already answered the question so this comment is moot

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The issue is that the *XML Source* is trying to validate the existence of the given file during the design time. However, you will know the file name only during runtime when the *Foreach loop container* executes and loops through every XML file available in a given folder.

I recreated an SSIS 2012 package using my answer to one of other SO questions.
[**SSIS reading multiple xml files from folder**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6957825/756519)

I was able to reproduce the error `The property "XMLDataVariable" on the XML Source was empty`

[image: Error]

On the XML source, I set the property `ValidateExternalMetadata` to `False`. Setting this to false will force the package not to verify the existence of the xml file path during design time.

[image: ValidateExternalMetadata]

I was successfully able to execute the package.

[image: Successful execution]

Hope that helps.

Comment: I linked your great answer in my blogpost: http://blog.haunschmid.name/ssis-tips-error-when-file-path-variable-is-not-set-at-design-time/ thanks!