# Using a variable to process all *.xml files using SSIS

Tags: sql, xml, ssis, sql-agent-job

I am new to SSIS package, so any help would be really appreciated.
The SSIS code was built using the VS2005 and its setup as a SQL agent Job in the 2005 SQL Server. Now as we are migrating to 2016 SQL server we see that the same SQL agent Job fails.
Hence we decided to rebuild the package using VS2012, to see if that would solve the issue.

Processes done on the Control Flow Tab:
[image]

Data Flow task:
[image]

Variables used:
[image]

we have used a ForEachLoop:
[image]

Errors Show in the Data Flow Task:
[image]

[image]

We are still not able to make out what's causing the issue, we also refereed the full step by step process given in the below link.

Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6956409/ssis-reading-multiple-xml-files-from-folder)!

If any more information is required I can provide that too!!

XML Source Editor Error:
[image]

XML Source Advanced Editor:
[image]

XML Source Components Tab:
[image]

XML Source Connection manager tab:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I'd rather use VS 2015 for packages targeting SSIS 2016.
2. Your error comes from DataFlow task - XML Source. At Validation step, which occurs on Package Save, XML Source tries to open XML file using `sXMLfilename` variable value; the value of `sXMLfilename` at this moment in VS is the variable default value. Therefore, validation in Visual Studio fails and you see the error messages.
   To pass validation, XML source should be able to open both XML and XSD file. Check for these files at Developer's station, migrate files if necessary from your old server. For XML file you can use any valid XML input file, XSD schema should match it. Specify **valid path to XML file** as the default value for `sXMLfilename` variable.

Comment: The XML files and the XSD are both placed in the location as set in the SSIS package, also ReadOnly is not checked in. Still the issue persists, anything else that might be causing the issue ?

Comment: @Joby, try to open XML Source, and hit Ok, or in Advanced Editor - hit Refresh button. If error persists - please post screenshots of XML Source Editor.

Comment: I have added the screenshots of both from the normal editor and Advanced Editor, can you please take a look.

Comment: @Joby, thanks for the screenshot. Unfortunately, it is not the right one and gives no insight. Please, post - open XML Source editor and post Connections Manager window (1st one), and open XML Src Advanced editor and show Component Properties tab.

Comment: Hey @Ferdipux, have added the new screenshots, hope this time I have added it right :)

Comment: @Joby, this time is fine. On the "Variables" screen your variable `sXMLFileName` has default value *filename*. Your XML Source at Validation event (which fires when you save your package in VS) tries to load file specified by this variable. Please mind - it happens not at runtime, but when VS is saving package; at this moment the variable is initialized with its default value.  
Way to fix - adjust `sXMLFileName` default value to point to valid XML file.

Comment: can we leave the `sXMLFileName` blank, would that fetch all the XML files. As we the files that are posted in the path don't follow a naming convention. Our expectation is to process all files that have an extension *.XML

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135072/discussion-between-ferdipux-and-joby).

Comment: Thanks the SSIS package is working fine now, also Job also executes the package successfully.

Just adding the change that was done as advised by Ferdipux
Set the **Delay Validation** property to `True`.