# SSIS Visual Studio 2012 XML File Source says file not found

Tags: sql-server, xml, validation, visual-studio-2012, ssis

I have a folder with multiple xml files and need to loop through it and load xml data into Database. But for the XML Source i added a path to the xml files but it throws error saying

> Package Validation Error

*ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:*

> Error at GTN Load [GTN XML [43]]: The file "C:\SSIS\XML Files" was not found. Please verify the file path and try again.
>   Error at GTN Load [SSIS.Pipeline]: "XML" failed validation and returned validation status "VS_ISBROKEN".
>   Error at GTN Load [SSIS.Pipeline]: One or more component failed validation.
>   Error at GTN Load: There were errors during task validation (Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.VsIntegration)

Comment: The error seems very clear: **The file "C:\SSIS\XML Files" was not found.** Do you have a file named *XML FIles* in the folder *C:\SSIS*? (Note the word **file** in the error message, the space in the filename and lack of a file extension before you rush to answer.) As far as your code, we can't debug code we can't see, and we can't see your screen from where we are - see [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Updated formatting

Comment: Looks like your XML Source connection is not configured correctly. Are you using a Foreach Loop Task to iterate through the files in your folder?

Comment: Take a look at this SO Q&A to see how to properly configure a loop to get all the filenames and paths from a folder. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38151342/ssis-how-to-loop-through-files-in-folder-and-get-pathfile-names-and-finally-e

Comment: @digital.aaron Yes I am using a for each loop to iterate which works fine but the XML Source previously in SQL Server BI 2008 it used to accept the path to the folder but now i migrated to SSIS 2012 which throws this error.

Answer (score 2):

I actually found the same error in stackoverflow ([Using a variable to process all *.xml files using SSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42062228/using-a-variable-to-process-all-xml-files-using-ssis)) and tried the solution in SSIS 2012 and it worked after that.

*Change the VaidateExternalMetadata to false*

[image: Change the VaidateExternalMetadata to false]